# 'AppDelegate' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am declaring AppDelegate instance for calling method reside in AppDelegate but it is giving me error as **'AppDelegate' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer**, but I want to use AppDelegate instance in iOS 9 also. If I will change my deployment target as iOS 10 then the code is working fine for me but I can not able to run project with deployment target 9.0. I am using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2 in my Xcode project.

Please check my below code and let me know if I am doing something wrong
[image].

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.ShowErrorPopUpWithErrorCode(strError:"This is test error message")
```

Appreciated your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an available check in your `AppDelegate` class like `@available(iOS 10, *)`?

Comment: Could you post a little more code? Maybe what's before that statement and/or your app delegate code?

Comment: @ViralMithani `@available(iOS 10, *)` means that the class is only available on devices with iOS 10 or later. Imho the `AppDelegate` shouldn't rely on any version at all. What's the problem if you remove the availability check?

Comment: Thanks @AndréSlotta, @available(iOS 10, *) is there in my AppDelegate class, I have removed it and my problem has been solved.

Comment: You‘re welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something like this on you're app delegate:
[image: App Delegate]

And obviously this way you cannot call app delegate

[image]

Either change your minimum deployment target or use frameworks that work with every iOS version you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks Mykod for solving my problem. By default when I am creating new Xcode project at that time @available(iOS 10.0, *) is there in my code above @UIApplicationMain in AppDelegate file

Comment: @ViralMithani are you using core data?

Comment: I am not using core data in my current project.